# how can I make the password dots appear of those letters which have been typed except last one in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want input[type="password"] only hide the letters that have been typed by the user except the last one. 
If user is going to write more letters in password field, then the previous letters should hide by password dot and the last one should remain visible until the user typed new letter.
for more info image is:

[image: password image]

Comment: I don't have any idea about it how to do it I do not know I have to do it with pseudo class of css or with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One implementation is to create a new input type.. replace the typed characters with the bullet point except the last one and then, on a timeout, replace the last one as well.. Doing this will change the value of the input to a string of bullet points though, so in order to get the actual value typed you will have to use `myInput.getAttribute('data-value');` instead of `myInput.value`, which means you won't be able to submit it like a normal form.

```js
(()=>{
  var to;
  var fields = document.querySelectorAll('[type=fancyPassword]');
  Array.from(fields).forEach(ele=>{
    ele.setAttribute("data-value", "");
    ele.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
        if(to) clearTimeout(to);
        if(!this.value.length) return;
        var typed = this.value.split('').pop();
        this.setAttribute("data-value", this.getAttribute("data-value")+typed);
        this.value = "•".repeat(this.value.length-1)+typed;
        to = setTimeout(()=>this.value = "•".repeat(this.value.length),500);
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<input type=fancyPassword>
```